# Isn't 00.0 the same as 0.0?

Tags: ruby, numbers

I just found a strange problem in the programming language ruby, it isn't a big problem, but I just can't understand why it happens. It would interest me if someone knows the problem for my problem.

In ruby you can write `0` or `00`, that doesn't matter, it comes to the same result.
If you run `0 === 00` you also get `true` meaning that the two inputs are exactly the same.

`0.0` also equals `0`, so logically `00.0` should also equal `0.0` but the problem is,
that if you try to use the number `00.0` then you'll just get an error. If you run for example:

```
a = 00.0
```

You get this error:

> syntax error, unexpected tINTEGER

Of course I know this is a small problem, but as said I'd like to understand why the computer doesn't treat `00.0` the same as `0.0`?

Comment: Is 00.0 even mathematically legitimate?

Comment: It is _mathematically_ legitimate. The question is if it's legitimate in ruby.

Comment: I'll just make this a comment, since I have no concrete basis for this. An idea, though, is that perhaps Ruby evaluates 0 === 00 on a bit level, but once you add a decimal, the evaluation is done as floats? At which point 00.0 isn't a legit input and probably won't equal anything, I would think.

Comment: Chances are the preceding preceding 0 turns what the OP believes to a float into an Octal literal (similar to C/C++) and therefore it parses it as a `tINTEGER` rather than a `tFLOAT`.

Comment: Yes of course a human being will see it as 0. But in math, if you want 3 significant digits, I believe you should write 0.000, while if you want 3 decimal place, you should write 0.000. I never see 00.0 in any of math or other course textbook throughout my life.

Comment: === is NOT a strict ==! It is in other languages, but not in ruby. Straight from the docs: Case Equality---For class Object, effectively the same as calling  #==, but
typically overridden by descendants to provide meaningful semantics in case
statements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing is that when parsing and ruby sees that a number with more than two digits starts with the character 0, it parses it as an octal integer number. Thus, when it parses 00, it is 0 in octal which is the same as 0 in decimal. But if it finds a . then it is an invalid integer and that is the error it shows.

Comment: Actually the `00.` part is still fine, Ruby is treating it as a method invokation on the Fixnum (singleton) object `0`, and expect a valid symbol for method name following the period. E.g., `00.class # => Fixnum`. However, since the last `0` is not a valid symbol, it is a syntax error. Hence the error message (The error message provided by the OP makes more sense than `SyntaxError: no .<digit> floating literal anymore put 0 before dot.`).

Answer (score 1):

I tried "a = 00.0" in http://tryruby.com, and got:

```
SyntaxError: no .<digit> floating literal anymore put 0 before dot. near line 1: ""
```

Clearly the Ruby lexer isn't expecting that form of float.